# Optimize one to many relation in same table query

Tags: sql, sql-server

with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE LookUp
([docID] varchar(10), [docType] varchar(100), [PartNumber] varchar(100), [internalID] varchar(100));
INSERT INTO LookUp
([docID],[docType],[PartNumber], [internalID])
VALUES
('D0305415', 'docTypeSub', 'X0455', null),
('D0157632', 'docTypeMain', null, 'XY05570-XY05571'),
('D0181511', 'docTypeMain',null, 'XY05572-XY05573'),
('D0157633', 'docTypeMain',null, 'XY06380-XY06381'),
('D0156037', 'docTypeSub', 'X0326', null),
('D0151874', 'docTypeMain', null, 'XY05345');

CREATE TABLE Links
([docIDTop] varchar(10), [docIDBottom] varchar(10));
INSERT INTO Links
([docIDTop],[docIDBottom])
VALUES
('D0157632', 'D0305415'),
('D0181511', 'D0305415'),
('D0157633', 'D0305415'),
('D0151874', 'D0156037');
```

there any way to optimize this query without using a nested 'select', I think there is a way, but I can't remember ;P. The Lookup table has one to many relation inside, when doctype is 'doctypeSub' there is the master row, used in the links table to relation with the lookup table (again) with their details.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT INTERNALID,
(SELECT PARTNUMBER 
 FROM LOOKUP X2 
 WHERE X2.DOCID = Z.DOCIDBOTTOM) PARTNUMBER 
FROM LOOKUP X
INNER JOIN LINKS Z
ON X.DOCID = Z.DOCIDTOP) TB
```

Comment: Can you describe what you want the query to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it difficult to figure out what your query should be doing.  But, I think this is equivalent:

```
     SELECT X.INTERNALID, X2.PARTNUMBER 
     FROM LOOKUP X INNER JOIN
          LINKS Z
          ON X.DOCID = Z.DOCIDTOP INNER JOIN
          LOOKUP X2
          ON X2.DOCID = Z.DOCIDBOTTOM;
```

Comment: awesome, lol how I could not see, its time to rest, thank you.

Comment: if I think that is question it is very silly, can I erase it?.